# How to send Boolean value in params?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
     this.apiService.sendRequest(requests.getAllInternalStatuses+ '?isInternal=' +isInternal, 'get')
     .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.tableData = res.data;
      console.log("Table Data",this.tableData);
     })
```

`/admin/application-has-status?isInternal=true`

above is the endpoint and the params value.
I'm using this api to send isInternal=true, but it gives me an error saying that isInternal must be a boolean value. Can anyone help me with this, how to send boolean value in params?

Comment: If apiService documentation says you can pass boolean only by get parameter and it anyway gives you that error, means, you missed something in documentation how to pass argument or they have bug :D Also you may create a reproducible example to help us to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

We need more context to understand what is going on. Basically it says that you need to pass argument as a boolean `true` or `false` but you are passing string.

```
this.apiService.sendRequest(true, 'get') //or false instead of true
.subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.tableData = res.data;
    console.log("Table Data", this.tableData);
})
```

Comment: Yes, tell me where

Answer (score 0):

you should declare isInternal as a boolean above :

```
isInternal: boolean = false;
```